# Rest services returning byte - Slow performance

Tags: java, performance, rest, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a rest service which returns byte[] contents. Internally it reads a 5 MB image file and return that in byte[]. Consumer on the other hand is using http client commons library GETMethod to execute the request and response from rest service is binded to a view object which renders it in browser as a image file.
This entire process is fine when image size is 1MB or less but when image size increases we are expriencing slow responses.

Comment: Do you use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for the image ? It is slow coming up the image in the browser ?

Comment: The download window it takes some 15 sec to come up.